# Is it triggers or what?

Tags: mysql, workbench, forward-engineer

[image]

I used forward engineer functionality to auto generate my db schema.
There are "ON DELETE, and ON UPDATE", I understand that this specifies what happen to the rows in table when the referenced table changes. Is that Trigger, or what because it is written in constraint part?
Part of code below:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `la`.`trainers`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `la`.`trainers` (
  `login` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`login`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `la`.`sexes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `la`.`sexes` (
  `id` ENUM('M', 'F') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO sexes VALUES ('M'),('F');

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `la`.`athletes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `la`.`athletes` (
  `pesel` BIGINT(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `sex_id` ENUM('M', 'F') NOT NULL,
  `trainer_login` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pesel`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_athletes_trainers`
    FOREIGN KEY (`trainer_login`)
    REFERENCES `la`.`trainers` (`login`)
    ON DELETE SET NULL  -- W przypadku usunięcia przez trenera konta, wszytkim zawodnikom
                        -- tego trenera zostanie ustawiony trener_login = NULL
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT, -- Nie można uaktualniać loginu trenera, jeśli jakikolwiek zawodnik jest z nim związany
  CONSTRAINT `fk_athletes_sexes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sex_id`)
    REFERENCES `la`.`sexes` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT -- Nie można usunąć płci jeśli jakikolwiek zawodnik ją posiada
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT)-- Nie można uaktualniać płci jeśli jakikolwiek zawodnik ją posiada
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Not trigger, actions to be taken when an FK detects a change in referenced table. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Yes, I've read that, so what is it, is there a name for that, because it behaves like trigger doesn't it?